# Evaluate $10^{20231016} \pmod{1021}$ (Hint : $1021$ is a prime)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

> Evaluate $10^{20231016} \pmod{1021}$ (Hint : $1021$ is a prime)

Does anyone know how to solve this question?

I found that $10^{20231016} \pmod{1021}$ is equivalent to $10^{336} \pmod{1021}$ using Fermat's Little Theorem, but I don't know how to handle it in the following steps.

Comment: Try exponentiation by repeated squaring?

Comment: 20231016 looks suspiciously like a date that occurs later this month. This question may be part of an ongoing competition.

Comment: @peterwhy I’ll give it a try.

Comment: @DanielMathias Because it is my collage homework which deadline is on October 16th.

Comment: my question was solved.Thanks everyone!